# CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction created by:

Tags: multithreading, macos, cocoa, warnings

Details:

CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; created by:

0   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff86c516c2 _ZN2CA11Transaction4pushEv + 312

1   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff86c6c9a8 _ZN2CA11Transaction15ensure_implicitEv + 276

2   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff86c57907 _ZN2CA5Layer13thread_flags_EPNS_11TransactionE + 37

3   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff86c6f92d _ZN2CA5Layer13needs_displayEv + 45

4   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff86c6f8f8 -[CALayer needsDisplay] + 21

5   AppKit                              0x00007fff89a3df37 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 1078

6   AppKit                              0x00007fff89a3d2b0 -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:] + 1417

7   AppKit                              0x00007fff899f6f1a -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1216

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this **warning** from console in two different cases and have solved them with the same solutions.

The root cause is I just tried to update UI element in background thread, after I dispatch the update task to main thread, problem resolved.

Paste a helper function here,

```
void RunInMainThread(void (^block)(void))
{
    if (!block) {
        return;
    }

    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        block();
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of the helper function instead of a single         `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), …)`;

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad It depends, if the block executed in main thread, then there is no need to dispatch to the main queue.

Comment: That's right, but this check produces additional code and is not necessary. There is no advantage. Beside this, if you have functional code in the block, too, you will get the surprise that is it sometimes executed synchronously, sometimes asynchronously.